# Core Data - 1600 error (while deleting object with specific delete rules)

Tags: ios, core-data

The error happened to me after I had deleted *detail* object which had `nullify` rule on a relation to it's *master*. At the same time the *master* had `cascade` rule on a relation to *details* (reversed relationship). The error disappeared after I had changed the *detail's* rule from `nullify` to `no action`.

It still looks strange to me. Can't understand the cause for the error.
I can't just rely on a simple solution, I need to find out what is the reason of this strange behaviour.

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1600 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1600.)
```

Usually(in most cases) the 1600 error rises when the `deny` deletion rule gets triggered. But there is no `deny` rules in my case at all.

Comment: The relationship is optional at both ends?

Comment: Which type of relation on this objects? "to many" or "to one"?

Comment: @ilya master-detail is one-to-many

Comment: I couldn't create a clear example with same error by your description. I think you should complete this description with code that manage objects, object traces on moment when you perform deletion

Comment: @ilya did you get me right? Just to be clear, master has many details, detail has only one master.

Comment: @purrrminator yes i got it. But there is not enough info to analyse reason of your case

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error, and could fix it by first making fields that connect the entity to other tables nil, and only then calling the delete function and finally save.